# CORS Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http

I'm a beginner learning node and angular but running into many issues. I have Angular running on Node, and my code in Angular makes http requests to retrieve json from an API on another web server (this web server is something I add routes to and I'm not allowed to enable CORS on it). I'm getting 'CORS blocked' due to my http request although I know this resource is accessible. I understand that you have to enable CORS in the web server but in this case that is not an option. There is another web app (not running on the same origin as the resource) that is doing a similar thing to mine but instead he uses node to retrieve the json data and then I think he sends that to angular to process. Is this a possible work around?

Comment: yes, there is no cross-domain restriction on the server. we make third-party web service call all the time on server.

Comment: so I can just make an http request in node and send the data to angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. If you can't enable cors headers on the server then the only thing you can do is access the server from your nodejs or any other type of server. If you eventually plan to run your angular in cordova you could make a direct $http request because cordova does not block corsable requests.

Comment: Awesome thank you! Once I get the json data in Node, will I have to serialize it and send it to angular?

Comment: If you get it serialized  allready in your response you could also directly pass it, but I think you have to do some research (google) on that.